# .Net Core 3.1 and Angular compile verbosity in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, configuration, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, verbosity

I have a .Net Core 3.1 project with Angular (I think 8) UI, created from the standard project template. I have worked on this for many months. Every time I start debugging (F5) in *Visual Studio 2019 Pro* I see the **command window popup**, display a ton of info, and then my web browser starts with my app. Great.

Lately (I think after my last VS update) the info has disappeared from the **command window**, and from the **output window** when I publish the app (again from VS 2019). Now it looks like my VS is hanging mid-publish, but it's hard to tell because all the useful info has been removed. So annoying.

Anyone know what I can do to get the verbose info back? I can't find any config options in VS

Comment: First of all, this is necessary to say that **Command Windows** is not designed to report what happens. This is writable in order to perform commands. You mean **Output Window** with is designed for reporting purpose.

Answer (score 0):

check `Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Build and Run` and change values of `"MSBuild project build output verbosity"`

Comment: This only affects the verbosity of the project compilation n the VS output window. I do not get any of the information in the command window that indicates why my angular app is not compiling. All the messages give positive results but my client side app is not compiling or running

Comment: for Angular, you can run your angular project in Webstorm. it's the best IDE for angular. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can change the options from here.

Comment: This only affects the verbosity of the project compilation n the VS output window. I do not get any of the information in the command window that indicates why my angular app is not compiling. All the messages give positive results but my client side app is not compiling or running

Answer (score 0):

Note That **Output Window** is designed to show reports, not **Command Window**. In order to solve your problem, Consider the following cases.

The **Output window** can be extended by adding to its collection of text panes programmatically, but out of the box with a typical project most users will see the following:

- **Build**: Contains messages about builds and their status (e.g.
  compilation warnings)
- **Build Order**: Same as “Build”, only the output is logically ordered
  for readability (vs chronological order)
- **Debug**: Contains messages from the debugger plus any text the
  application output during execution.

There may be required a proper choice after update in order to show desired reports. Clearly, *VS may reset defaults after update process*. So, please pay attention to this section.

Another possibility is unwanted project/solution changes **after re-openning** with the new VS version. This can cause some changes inside `.sln` or `.csproj` possibly.

**Note that** *we can't reproduce your problem*, but the above tips may solve yours.

**Update**

You can open `.csproj` file *with an editor* (without VS) and set a [Target build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019) like the following, perhaps [conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019), in order to show results into the output window and automate the build process :

```
<Target Name="AngularBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="npm run build" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Build shows success, because it shows the result of the .Net compilation. The command window used to show the result of the angular compilation, that is gone and that is where my project is failing. I am now completely stuck as I have no idea what the problem is and my project is broken

Comment: If I do a "npm run build -- --prod" command in the ClientApp folder then I get the output that shows me the "angular" compile errors that I need. How do i get Visual Studio back to the state where it displays that information when I start a debug of the web app?

Comment: @AdriaanDavel I added an update at the end of answer based on you current state.